# How to run Visual Studio 2005 Crystal Reports app on Windows 8.1 - says can't find CR runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I have a VS2005 forms app that uses Crystal Reports (built on a Windows Server 2003 system).  I can run the app in Windows 8.1, but when I try to open a report, I get an error saying it cannot find the Crystal Reports runtime.  I've installed the CR2005_x86 runtime, and the C++2005 runtime for good measure.

I've also installed VS2005 on the Win 8.1 machine (with its SP1 and SP1 for Vista), can open/edit the reports within VS2005, and can build the app, but this too says it cannot find the CR runtime.

In both cases running with Admin priviledges.

Can anyone help?  What am I missing or do I need to upgrade (eg to VS2012)?

Regards,
     Tom

Comment: Have you tried the 64 bit version of the CR runtime? just assuming you have 64 bit here.

Comment: Hi Sabre
Many thanks!  This worked flawlessly!  I installed cr_net_2005_x64.msi and my app produces its reports perfectly.